# Reflection: How to get the value of a field without evaluation?

Tags: java, reflection

Playing with `java.lang.reflect` and was wondering if there is any possibilities to get the assignment value of a `java.lang.reflect.Field`

Example

```
public class Dummy {
    String envHttpPort = System.getenv("HTTP_PORT");
}
```

From java reflection I would like the have the value `System.getenv("HTTP_PORT");` returned instead of `null` as it seems by instantiation of the class, which as far as I know is required to retrieve the values of the Field would be the value of the System.getenv(String) call, which is not what I want.

Is it possible to read the field and value as is?

Wanted output would be the same as the source code.

I hope you guys understand if not please let me know and I will try and rephrase the question.

Comment: So you're trying to get back the piece of code `System.getenv("HTTP_PORT")` and evaluate it yourself, or something like that? Why? I suspect there's a simpler/better way to solve whatever problem you're working on...

Comment: I agree with Matt. This looks like another case of [X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: The reason I ask is I want my source code to be able to generate documentation with the endpoints I use in System.getenv by using a prefix / could use annotation I would presume, and other reason to be able to view the "real" value of Field x would be to reduce the duplicate. 


Imagine you would write many environmental variables and you need to copy those to the JavaDoc, instead my vision would be to run this parallel to a built or test and get a report of the environment variables, or the route endpoints.

Comment: Why don't you parse the source code instead of running it and trying to make it talk about itself?

Comment: You don't need an instance of an environment variable value per class instance. Why would you not make the field static and avoid the whole problem? Then reflection would  work without instantiation.

Comment: @TamasHegedus Yes I thought about that solution, I will sketch on a solution for the fun of learning more.
Thanks all of you for discussing this with me.

Comment: I think it would be feasible if JVM didn't have type erasure.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to get "the assignment value" of a field, (as you have arbitrarily defined it for the purpose of this question,) because as you have already seen, it is not a value, it is a piece of code.

This code is part of the initialization of the instance, and it cannot be extracted without bytecode manipulation.  Even if it could be extracted, it would only know how to set the value of a specific field of a specific class, it would not return any value that you can use.  It would also very likely invoke other code of the class to do its job, so even if you somehow managed to isolate it, it would not be possible to execute it outside of the normal initialization of the instance.

Long story short, don't even think of it.